PDDL in Visual Studio - Error: Using TensorFlow backend
I am trying to run a simple hello-world example in Visual Studio provided by the PDDL extension. I do right-click on the problem > PDDL: run the planner and display the plan.

Select one of the planners

And I get Error: Using TensorFlow backend.
I am not sure why this is the case. I had configured the extension as Planning as a service:

Thank you.

I think what is happening here is that the real error isn’t in the stderr (which is what you’re seeing, and is just an info statement), but rather in the planner output. You can try selecting another planner from that list (e.g., lama-first), and see what it says in the output. I’ve tested all the remotely hosted planners, and they seem to be working fine at the time of writing — that said, it’s also possible that the server was having some issues when you first tried.
For future reference, you could reach out to those of us in the community at https://slack.planning.domains for issues like this and we would be glad to help out over there.

Thank you. Indeed I realised the plan shows the action "say-hello world" needed to complete the plan. I am not sure why this warning appears but I will ignore it.
